# insert rows on excel based on value in other column

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

New to this so bear with me.

I want to automatically insert a certain number or rows based on a value in another column. Can this be done?

eg

```
Container Lifts
B0237       1
B0238       7
B0239       7
A8783       2
```

So the containers would be split by the number of lifts

Answer (score 0):

One for loop nested in a while loop should do your job. Why we are suing while instead of for because we can not dynamically change the limit of For loop when we add a new row in between existing data. So there you go:

```
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim RowAddNo As Long
LastRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
i = 2
While i <= LastRow
    RowAddNo = Range("B" & i).Value
    For J = 1 To RowAddNo
        Rows(i + 1 & ":" & i + 1).Insert shift:=xlUp
        LastRow = LastRow + 1
        i = i + 1 'increasing the 'i' value to find the address for the next not empty row
    Next
    i = i + 1 'increasing the 'i' value to find the address for the next not empty row
Wend
```

PS: Do not try without i = i + 1. it goes in an endless loop :)

Comment: Row numbers don't always fit into Integers anymore, use Long

Answer (score 0):

This will do it for you:

```
Sub AddRows()
Dim X As Long
For X = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1 'Work backwards when inserting or deleting rows, so much easier than incrementing numbers
    Range("A" & X).Offset(1, 0).Resize(Range("B" & X).Value, 1).EntireRow.Insert 'Insert the number of rows against the target row offset by 1 ie below it
Next
End Sub
```